# vscode extension API - globalStorage folder deleted after upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I developed a VSCode extension which creates files under the context.globalStoragePath.
I then release a new version of the extension.
I noticed that the extension folder under the globalStoragePath was deleted after the upgrade.

Is there a way I can retain the folder so I would not lose the files during upgrade?